# ZedGraph: Won't work under button click event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, zedgraph

I a windows forms project in VS2012 with a ZedGraph Control and a button.  I have the following code:

```
double[] testing = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
LineItem myline = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.AddCurve("testing", testing, testing, Color.Red);
zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
```

When I have it under the Form_load event, the line chart is generated like it should be. However if I move the code under the button click event, nothing happens.  I just have a blank graph.

I've made sure the event is firing and when I look under the GraphPane.CurveList there is a curve with the expected values.

Can anyone suggest a reason why this might be happening?

Comment: Nevermind, I added zedGraphControl1.Invalidate() above and it works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have a solution for your problem. I have tried to solve it and the solution was very simple. At the end of your code try to add :

```
double[] testing = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
LineItem myline = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.AddCurve("testing", testing, testing, Color.Red);
zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();

ZedGraphControl1.Refresh()
```

But this will make changes after button clicking. For styling you have to write your code in 
Form_Load or in another sub.